# Operation on string inside function

Tags: c, char, reverse, c-strings, function-definition

Why does putting `reverse()` inside `main()` print `12345` while putting `reverse()` as the last statement of `itoa()` definition produces `54321`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void itoa(long n, char *s);
void reverse(char *s);

int main() {

    int n = 12345;
    char s[10];
    itoa(n, s);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}

void itoa(long n, char *s) {

    int i;
    while (n != 0) {
      *s++ = n % 10 + '0';
      n /= 10;
    }
    *s = '\0';
    reverse(s);
}

void reverse(char *s) {

    int i, temp, len = strlen(s);
    for (i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {
      temp = s[len - 1 - i];
      s[len - 1 - i] = s[i];
      s[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

I expected the output to be the same, since (I think, at least) I'm passing pointers as arguments to both functions.

Comment: Inside `itoa` you are calling `reverse` on `s`, which points to the terminating `\0`.

Comment: @materia-nigra, `char s[10];` is too small larger `n`  like for `itoa(1001001001, s)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the while loop within the function `itoa`

```
void itoa(long n, char *s) {

    int i;
    while (n != 0) {
    *s++ = n % 10 + '0';
    n /= 10;
    }
    *s = '\0';
    reverse(s);
}
```

the pointer `s` points to the zero character `'\0'` of the string.  So the function `reverse` reverses nothing.

You need to use an intermediate pointer in the function `itoa` and pass the original pointer to the function `reverse`.

Pay attention to that the parameter of the function `itoa` should be an unsigned integer type because the function does not take into account the sign of its argument.

Also the function does not process an argument equal to `0`.

The function can look the following way

```
char * itoa( unsigned int n, char *s ) 
{
    const unsigned int Base = 10;

    char *p = s;

    do
    {
        *p++ = n % Base + '0';
    } while ( n /= Base );

    *p = '\0';

    return reverse( s );
}
```

and the function `reverse` will look as

```
char * reverse( char *s ) 
{
    for ( size_t i = 0, n = strlen( s ); i < n / 2; i++ ) 
    {
        char c = s[n - 1 - i];
        s[n - 1 - i] = s[i];
        s[i] = c;
    }

    return s;
}
```